# C++14: this_thread::sleep_for in std::thread prevents .so unload

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, stdthread

I'm working on a plugin (GNU C++ 7.5.0/C++14/Ubuntu 18/amd64) that is being loaded through dynamic linking at runtime. When Test->run() gets called,

```
using namespace std;
class Test {
  thread t;
  void _run() {
    this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
  }
  void run() {
    t = thread(&Test::_run, this);
    t.join();
  }
}
```

the shared object file (.so) stops getting unloaded from the main program.

This does not happen when calling a member method of a different class or a static function.

What's the issue and is there any fix besides restructuring things?

The plugin host in question is Reaper (https://www.reaper.fm/), so I can't really say what's going on on the dlclose/host side, but I know that the Test class does not get deconstructed. But that's always the case, even when the unloading works.

## Update

Replaced this_thread::sleep_for with

```
this_thread::__sleep_for
```

and that somehow works. Here is the `<thread>` include file:

```
void
__sleep_for(chrono::seconds, chrono::nanoseconds);

/// sleep_for
template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
  inline void
  sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
  {
if (__rtime <= __rtime.zero())
  return;
auto __s = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(__rtime);
auto __ns = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(__rtime - __s);
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_NANOSLEEP
__gthread_time_t __ts =
  {
    static_cast<std::time_t>(__s.count()),
    static_cast<long>(__ns.count())
  };
while (::nanosleep(&__ts, &__ts) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
  { }
#else
__sleep_for(__s, __ns);
#endif
  }
```

Somehow, that template code is producing an STB_GNU_UNIQUE it seems (see [dlclose() doesn't work with factory function & complex static in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050693/dlclose-doesnt-work-with-factory-function-complex-static-in-function)). The --no-gnu-unique linker option seems not supported any more.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you're using -- a [mcve] if possible.  From what you've stated thus far I can't see any reason for the `dlclose` call to fail (assuming that's what you mean).  Are you sure that `<class>::<method>` doesn't create any new threads of its own that may result in the shared object being held open?

Comment: I'll just add a reminder here that identifiers that start with a double underscore (like `__sleep_for`) are internal implementation details of the standard library. That code won't work for libc++, or other standard libraries. And may not work on the next (or previous) version of libstdc++.

Comment: well, I guess I'll stick to C level stuff mostly then. Or does this get better with more recent GCCs?